# Aura set (set the value in aura iteration)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community

I am trying to set the value of `aura attribute` in `aura iteration`.I am declaring

```
<aura:attribute name="flag" type="integer" default="0"/>
```

And in `<aura:iteraton>` i am trying to set this flag value but i am unable to do it due to following error:

```
Failed to save undefined: The attribute "flag" was not found on the COMPONENT markup://aura:iteration: Source
```

And i am setting the value like following:

```
<aura:attribute name="flag" value="0" type="integer"/>
  <aura:iteration>
  <!-- some condition goes here to set the value-->
<aura:set attribute="flag" value="{add(v.flag,1)}"/>
</aura:iteration>
```

Comment: i think you missed `!`   HERE  `{!add(v.flag,1)}`

Comment: But i am not getting that error due to that i think.The error here means something different

Comment: Try this `type="Integer"` instead on `type="integer"` as we all know JS is case sensitive. This might be an issue.

Comment: Have tried Ratan's fix and have confirmed that it does not solve the problem?

Comment: No that didnt work.How ever my issue is resolved i found the other way around without using `<aura:set>`.Thanks anyways'

Comment: @DeepakAgarwal how did you solve it?

Comment: Here the thing is you cannot set the value inside <aura:iteration>

Answer (score 2):

`aura:set` doesn't work like this.

From the doc:

> When you include another component, such as , in a
>   component, we call that a component reference to . **You can
>   use  to set an attribute on the component reference**.

`aura:set` when used inside a parent element, it sets the value of the attribute of the parent element. Here, your parent element is `aura:iteration`, so its searching for an attribute on `aura:iteration` which is obviously not present.

The error you are getting is explaining the same:

> Failed to save undefined: The attribute "flag" was **not found on** the
>   COMPONENT **markup://aura:iteration**: Source

Comment: I tried to declare aura:set inside aura:iteration then also i am getting same error.

Comment: So what will be the otherway around this.