# increase sum in aura:iterator

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura, aura-attribute

How do I create a sum within an aura:iteration?

```
<aura:attribute name="sum" type="Integer"/>

<aura:iteration items="[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]" var="item">
    do something with {!item}
    <aura:set attribute="sum" value="{!v.sum + item}"/>
</aura:iteration>
```

`<aura:set attribute="sum"` won't work as figured out [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/171876/aura-set-set-the-value-in-aura-iteration)

- Is there any other way to change attributes within the markup?
- Should I throw events to sum it up with java script?
- Is it even considered good practice to do it within the markup?
- Or should I prepare the data before initializing the component?

Comment: for counter you can use attribute indexVar="counter" of aura:iteration and use it as {!counter} within interation.

Comment: @Animesh I'm more trying to use a calculated value after finishing the iteration to display the sum ect. I will remove the counter since it might be irritating.

Comment: then create an attribute of type Integer[] and initialise it during init.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot dynamically calculate the value of `sum` via markup expression in Lightning Component. You need to calculate the value in the controller.js and store in a separate attribute in the component during the initialization.

**markup**

```
<aura:attribute name="values" type="List" default="[0,0,1,0,0,1]" />
<aura:attribute name="sum" type="Interger" />

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.initHandler}" />

{!v.sum}
```

**controller:**

```
({
    initHandler : function(cmp) {
       var values = cmp.get("v.values");
       var total = values.reduce(function(sum, value) {
          return sum + value;
       });
       cmp.set("v.sum", total);
    }
})
```